# Closing a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm having rough times trying to close a modal with angularjs.
What I'm doing is open a simple modal when an event is triggered, do something inside the modal and then confirm or abort the operation.
The first opiton goes fine but when I click on the "Abort" button to close the modal the compilator says that close() is not a function.
I thought it was an instance problem so I created one and assigned the open() and close() methods to it but nothing changed... 
Here's the JS code:

```
angular.module("docAcquire.controllers")
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.modalInstance = $modal;

    $scope.openDoc = function() {
        $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'partials/modals/Doc.html',
            controller: '',
            size : 'lg',
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            resolve: {}
        });         
     };

    $scope.abortOperation = function() {
        $scope.modalInstance.close();       
     };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?! 
**EDIT: if you're going to downvote the question at least be man enough to explain why...**

Comment: Try removing `$scope.modalInstance = $modal;`.

Comment: @Tushar removing it would result in a call of an undefined object...

Comment: you didn't add $modalInstance in your controller that is why its showing error.

Comment: you need to add controller for it and inject $modalInstance service to that controller. With that service you can able to close modal. $modal.open function return different thing you can use it to resolve promise from modal or take action after modal closed...

Answer (score -1):

Yor didn't add $modalInstance in your controller.
You have two way to close modal

```
$scope.openDoc = function() {
    $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'partials/modals/Doc.html',
        size : 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        resolve: {},
        controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 
            function($scope, $modalInstance){

        //First Way
        $scope.abortOperation = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();       
         };
        //Second Way
        $scope.abortOperation = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');      
         };
    }]});
}
```

Comment: none of these two would work. They'd both return the same error I'm getting right now (undefined function)

Comment: add $modalIntance in your modal controller and try again

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work without having evidences of it ;)

Comment: then why give you down vote for my answer.
It should be work. see modal examples.